# Pyspark - Using a custom function in map transform

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I run the following file (called `test_func.py`) with `py.test`:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

def filtering(data):
    return data.map(lambda p: modif(p)).count()

def modif(row):
    row.split(",")   

class Test(object):
    sc = SparkContext('local[1]')

    def test_filtering(self):
        data = self.sc.parallelize(['1','2', ''])
        assert filtering(data) == 2
```

And, because the `modif` function is used inside the `map` transform, it fails with the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/osboxes/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.4/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 98, in main
    command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)
  File "/home/osboxes/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.4/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 164, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/home/osboxes/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.4/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 422, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj)
ImportError: No module named clustering.test_func
```

pyspark does not manage to find the `modif` function. Note that the file `test_func.py` is in the directory `clustering` and I run `py.test` from inside `clustering` directory.

What astonishes me is that if I use `modif` function outside a `map`, it works fine. For instance, if I do: `modif(data.first())`

**Any idea why I get such importErrors and how I could fix it?**

---

**EDIT**

1. I had already tested what has been proposed Avihoo Mamka's answer, i.e. to add `test_func.py` to the files copied to all workers. However, it had no effect. It is no surprise for me because I think the main file, from where the spark application is created, is always sent to all workers.
2. **I think it can come from the fact that** `pyspark` **is looking for** `clustering.test_func` **and not** `test_func`.

Comment: Just a thought, but a map executes the code block on every worker. Does it maybe has something to do with the workers does not recognize `modif` function?

Comment: Yeah, that was my bet. But I do not how to make it recognized by workers (just 1 here, as master is "local[1]")....

Answer (score 0):

The key here is the `Traceback` you got.

PySpark is telling you that the worker process doesn't have access to `clustering.test_func.py`. When you initialize the `SparkContext` you can pass a list of files that should be copied to the worker:

```
sc = SparkContext("local[1]", "App Name", pyFiles=['MyFile.py', 'lib.zip', 'app.egg'])
```

More information: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/programming-guide.html

Comment: I have tried this already: it does not change anything. Thank you for your input, anyway :)

Comment: Did you add the `test_func.py` to the SparkContext?

Comment: Yes, I have tried: `sc = SparkContext("local[1]", pyFiles=['test_func.py'])` and `os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = "--files test_func.py --py-files test_func.py pyspark-shell"`